# Varioref: How to make "on the following page" and similar into hyperlinks?

Tags: hyperref, varioref

Using `cleveref`, `varioref`, and `hyperref`, I am producing such text as

> See Figure 9 on the following page.

This example provides only a small hyperlink target: just the "9."  But I have promised my publisher that the text "on the following page" will also be hyperlinked.  (The details don't matter too much; it would also be OK just to hyperlink "following page" or "the following page.")

I've delved into the documentation, and it looks like `\autoref` (from `hyperref`) provides larger target links.  What would I need to do to get similar functionality from `varioref`?  I'm currently thinking in terms of redefining `\vref` so I can grab the label and redefine `\reftextafter` and friends to be hyperlinks.  Does that sound like it might work?  Is there a better tactic?

In the following MWE, only the "1" in "fig. 1" is a link target.  I'd like "on the following page" to be highlighted also.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

% what hacks to insert here?

\begin{document}
Please see \vref{example}.
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
This is it.
\caption{Example}
\label{example}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

without cleveref it would work, as hyperref handles this. But cleveref destroys the code again. You could try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varioref}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\def\cref@vref#1#2{%
    \leavevmode%
    \begingroup%
    \@crefstarredtrue
    \let\T@pageref\@pagerefstar
    \def\reftextcurrent{}%
    \hyperref[#2]{%  
      \@cref{#1}{#2}\@setcref@space%
      \cref@@vpageref{\reftextcurrent}[]{#2}}%
    \endgroup}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Please see \vref{example}.
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
This is it.
\caption{Example}
\label{example}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be a little fairer to say instead that `cleveref` has chosen not to include the page reference part in the link? Besides, it has the `nameinlink` option, which already makes for a larger clickable object.

Comment: @gusbrs cleveref describes this under "Known Bugs and Work-Arounds" and it refers there to a behaviour which is no longer true.

Comment: Ulrike, I've put some thought inon this for `zref-vario` and I think I got to an interesting balance. Perhaps it may interest you: https://github.com/gusbrs/zref-vario/commit/a637d7d19404700750e0edd891410de4b78f877e. Coming to you soon on the next release.

Answer (score 1):

At least for this MWE a good option is remove `cleveref`:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}

% what hacks to insert here?
    \usepackage[nospace]{varioref}
    \usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
    %%%%% \usepackage{cleveref} 
    \labelformat{figure}{fig.~#1}

\begin{document}

Please see \vref{example}.

\clearpage
\begin{figure}
This is it.
\caption{Example}
\label{example}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not an option, alas.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the following code hasn't blown up on me:

```
\makeatletter  % add targets to \vref

\let\nr@orig@vref=\vref
\def\vref#1{%
  \begingroup
    \let\nr@fa\reftextfaceafter
    \let\nr@a\reftextafter
    \let\nr@b\reftextbefore
    \let\nr@fb\reftextfacebefore
    \def\reftextfaceafter{\hyperref[#1]{\nr@fa}}%
    \def\reftextafter{\hyperref[#1]{\nr@a}}%
    \def\reftextbefore{\hyperref[#1]{\nr@b}}%
    \def\reftextfacebefore{\hyperref[#1]{\nr@fb}}%
    \nr@orig@vref{#1}%
  \endgroup
}

\makeatother
```

Comment: you are making the command fragile.